# Retain values between sessions

Tags: dynamic

This is a real newbie question, so apologies in advance for may seem a very dumb question ... I'm trying to understand the various ways in which information can be retained in a notebook between sessions, using `DynamicModule[]` etc. Understanding how a good MMA user would solve the following simple task would be really helpful:

Say I want to load a video file and then create a simple slider to scroll through the frames. This works:

```
frames = Import["myvideofile.avi", {"Frames", All}]; 
Manipulate[frames[[f]], {f, 1, Length[frames],1}]
```

But, say I want to remember which frame the slider was left at between Mathematica sessions, how would I do that elegantly? If I re-open the code above, there's an error because 'frames' isn't defined until the video is imported.

In other words, upon re-opening the notebook, the first thing I'd like to happen is for 'frames' to be imported. I'm speculating that I need `DynamicModule`, with `Initialization` but have tried many different ways and can't get it to work.

Comment: Check `SaveDefinitions -> True` option of `Manipulate` and as well as the `Initialization` possibility.

Comment: You may also use simply `ListAnimate[frames]`which should remember its content across session. Re-using those will be more tricky though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the following will do what you want

```
Manipulate[frames[[f]], {f, 1, Length[frames], 1},SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

and this is faster in this case than importing the frames through `Initialization` option of `Manipulate`.

[image]

You can see while opening the notebook `Slider` remains in the same place as it was when the notebook was closed for the last time. The second version involving `Initialization` also does the job you want but it takes much time to load in the first place. This happens as `Initialization` needs first to import your data. In such time consuming cases we often need to override the initialization time out using `SynchronousInitialization -> False`.